# Supabase: RLS auth.uid() = user_id is false in Next.js route handler

Tags: reactjs, next.js, routes, handler, supabase

I'm having an issue when in my Next.js application when trying to fetch data via a route handler.

My database has a users table that contains an ID called `user_id` that matches the uid of the authenticated user, and `aps_id` which I use to make a call to a 3rd party API.

If I do not have RLS enabled on the table, I get the row returned as expected when I do a match for user ID.

If I have RLS enabled with the rule `auth.uid() = user_id` I get no rows returned.

I have the following code in my route handler:

route.ts

```
import { createRouteHandlerClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs';
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function GET() {
    try {
        const supabase = createRouteHandlerClient({ cookies });

        const { data: userData } = await supabase.from('users').select('aps_id').single();
        const apsId = userData?.aps_id;
        const {
            data: { user },
        } = await supabase.auth.getUser();

        console.log(user); // no user being returned?


        const res = await fetch(process.env.APS_API_URL + 'ClientEligibility/' + apsId, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'apiKey': process.env.APS_API_KEY || ''
            }
        });
    
        const data = await res.json();

        console.log(data); // this is null, but it should be returning a row?
    
        return NextResponse.json({ data });
    } catch(e) {
        console.error(e);

        return NextResponse.json({ error: e }, { status: 500 });
    }
}
```

It seems like there's no user session data coming back, so I assume auth.uid() in the RLS policy is also resulting in null.

Is there another necessary step required to get the user session in a route handler?

If I do not have RLS enabled on the table, I get the row returned as expected when I do a match for user ID.
If I have RLS enabled with the rule `auth.uid() = user_id` I get no rows returned.

Answer (score 0):

I found an article by Jon Meyers at Supabase shortly after posting this which explains the issue (not really an issue, but intented behavior):

https://jonmeyers.io/blog/forwarding-cookies-from-server-components-to-route-handlers-with-next-js-app-router

TL;DR: manually add headers to your fetch request using next/headers:

```
import { headers } from "next/headers";

export default async function Page() {
  await fetch("http://localhost:3000/test", {
    headers: headers(),
  });

  return ...
}
```